# Where does the do_generic_file_read() function sleep in case page is not found in inode's cache?

Tags: linux-kernel, filesystems

In case of a read io operation, the do_generic_file_read function is called for the ext3 filesystem. In case the inode's page cache does not contain the page from which the data needs to be read, the filesystem specific readpage address space function pointer is called. In case of ext3 filesystem ext3_readpage() function is called which in turn calls the generic do_mpage_readpage() function. The do_mpage_readpage() function creates a bio which is dispatched to get the data from the device through submit_bio() function and the control in turn returns to the do_generic_file_read() function. However in the do_generic_file_read(), the next instruction executed is to check if the page for which the bio was submitted is uptodate or not. In this flow, where does the kernel wait for the bio operation to get completed and update the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The do_mpage_readpage function creates bio structure to get the data from the disk blocks and submits them for io.

```
do_mpage_readpage
..
mpage_bio_submit(READ, bio)
..
```

When the bio is submitted, the control returns to the do_generic_file_read() function and then the lock_page_killable() function is called which waits on the uptodate  bit of the page.

```
do_generic_file_read()
...
        if (!PageUptodate(page)) {
            error = lock_page_killable(page); <<<<<<<< it sleeps here
...
```

Once the io is completed from the device, the mpage_end_io() is called as the return handler.(As we have filled bio->bi_end_io = mpage_end_io while submitting the IO). In case of a read, this marks the pages for which the bio was sent as Uptodate and the unlock_page() function is called. This function wakes up the control which was waiting for the page to get uptodated.

```
mpage_end_io
...
            unlock_page(page); <<< this wakes up the waiting do_generic_file_read
...
```